# Extract recognized text Tesseract while processing

Tags: tesseract

I've been using Tesseract and it works fine. But when the image has "alot" of text, the processing takes a little longer (especially on mobile devices).

Is there any way to extract the text "on the go" with tesseract?

Instead of getting the full text at completion, maybe get each line as soon as its recognized, in a callback for example?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `Recognize(ETEXT_DESC* monitor)` method. Some discussion can be found in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/tesseract-ocr/callback/tesseract-ocr/W9J_3oe8le8/ZDShpR-eJAIJ).